# Wakanda websocket onclose not firing on network disconnect

Tags: wakanda

I have a websocket implementation on Wakanda Server. I am tracking connected browsers server side. When I reload the page, I get the onclose event of the websocket as expected.

I would have expected when I break a network connection that I would also have this event fire. Am I misunderstanding? Is there a way to have a function fire when a network connection is lost to a websocket client?

For reference, I am using Wakanda 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help you understand the problem I will give you some details about websocket connections :

- It uses TCP
- If a remote client(browser for instance) closes a TCP connection gracefully the server is notified (FIN)
- If a remote client crashes, the OS running the client application notifies the server (RST)
- If a TCP connection is open between a server and a client the connection will be assumed open even if there is absolutely no exchange of data for a while unless **keepalive** is activated.
- The WebSocket spec adds a close message so the server/client can handle a graceful close
- The WebSocket spec adds a ping/pong message exchange but does not impose a timeout. From [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) :  `Upon receipt of a Ping frame, an endpoint MUST send a Pong frame in response, unless it already received a Close frame. It SHOULD respond with Pong frame as soon as is practical.`
- In Wakanda's implementation of the RFC we respond to received `ping` messages but don't send our own `ping` messages

This can be a new feature where we can either :

- expose a `ping` method through the `message port` with a `pong timeout`
- add a websocket keepalive option with configurable timeout at the moment of adding the `websocket handler`.
- add a TCP keepalive option with configurable timeout at the moment of adding the `websocket handler`.

For the time being, you can send a message of your choice to the client side every **N** seconds and wait for a response with a timeout of **T**. If you don't receive a response you can assume the connexion is lost and close it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After reading some other websocket implementation specs I figured it was something similar. I think it would be a great feature to consider, but that is up to your team!